# How to modify / add to Cookie in JMeter?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jmeter

I'm very new to JMeter and need your help on how to modify a cookie.

Here is the scenario:
I'm testing an assessment/test taking website that offers multiple answers to questions. When a user makes his selections and hits the submit button, the JavaScript in the page appends his answers (e.g., "Answers = BBAACDA...") to the cookie and makes the next GET request (instead of a POST request!).

Since, JMeter does not execute JavaScript (as popularly mentioned in its manual - it's not a browser), it cannot append the answers to the cookie. As a result, my test plan fails to recognize user interaction.

How can I add/append/modify a dynamic cookie? Thanks in advance!

--Ishti

Comment: Have you tried creating an HttpHeaderManager and setting the cookies there? http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager

Comment: If answer is ok for you, you should accept it so that it's helpful to others

Comment: Sorry, I'm working on it. So far, I could not solve this. I'll update you as soon as I get any results. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Beanshell pre-processor or better a Jsr223 Pre-Processor with groovy and use code mentionned here:

- http://javaworks.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/setting-cookie-in-jmeter/

Code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;  
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("<NAME>","<VALUE>","<HOST>","/",false,0);
manager.add(cookie);
```

Comment: For the <Name>, <Value> and <Host>: these should be my parameters, right? E.g., NAME = Answers, VALUE=ABCDABB----. What will be the value for HOST? Thanks.

Comment: yes, for host the same value that your test uses in Http sampler

Comment: Great thanks! A quick run shows some warnings and errors. I'll have to dig little deeper. Right now I'm caught with something else at work. Will definitely come back asap!

Comment: The errors were because of the inverted commas in the sample code (”). Once I changed them to the proper ones (") there were no errors and it could add in the cookie as I wanted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement some changes in the code that worked for me:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;  
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("<NAME>","<VALUE>","<DOMAIN>","<PATH>",false,0, true, true, 0);
manager.add(cookie);
```

Following the definition in http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/Cookie.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to modify or add a cookie manually in a groovy pre-processor script in the same way as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38505077/5747304.

Here's how to find and edit a cookie by browsing all cookies in the cookie manager:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;  
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

log.info("#########################################################################");
// cookie manager
CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();

def NbOfCookies = manager.getCookieCount();

for (def i = 0; i < NbOfCookies; i++) {
    log.info("Cookie n° " + (i+1) + ": " + manager.get(i).getName() + ": " + manager.get(i).getValue());
    if (manager.get(i).getName() == "Cookie_name_to_find") {
        log.info("MAJ of Cookie_name_to_find");
        manager.get(i).setValue("New_cookie_value");
        log.info("-> " + manager.get(i).getName() + ": " + manager.get(i).getValue());
    }
}

log.info("#########################################################################");
```

Here is the list of cookie manager methods like add or delete ...: http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.html.

Here is the list of cookie methods to modify more properties like the domain, its expiration date ...: http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/Cookie .html

It should be known that according to the standart chosen in the cookie manager, the manually modified values can still be modified by the manager before the request so you have to be careful.