# How to change cookie values between pages in JMeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I know how to modify cookies using BeanShell PreProcessor from:
[How to modify / add to Cookie in JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206418/how-to-modify-add-to-cookie-in-jmeter)

Thanks to PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE for the answer!

Now, my question is: how do I modify the cookie value between pages? Let me explain, I've a cookie called 'Answers' that for the first page is empty, i.e., Answers="" (empty), then in second page takes the value Answers="-,-,-,-,-,-"; finally in a third page it takes a longer value Answers="-,A,B,-,C,- ..."

How do I modify the same cookie in different pages? I have seen the CookieManager API: http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.html

But can anyone please explain with an example? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there cannot be 2 cookies having the same name, the [CookieManager](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.java) is smart enough to replace existing cookie with a new value (see `removeMatchingCookies(c); // Can't have two matching cookies` line)

So

1. Request 1: nothing required as you cannot send a cookie having empty value
2. Requests 2 and 3: Add a [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) with the same code like:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

   CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getProperty("HTTPSampler.cookie_manager").getObjectValue();
   Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Answers", "**VALUE**", sampler.getDomain(), sampler.getPath(), false, System.currentTimeMillis());
   manager.add(cookie);
   sampler.setCookieManager(manager);
   ```

   Where `**Value**` for Request 2 will be `-,-,-,-,-,-` and for Request 3 will be `-,A,B,-,C,- ...`

For more information on Beanshell scripting and kind of Beanshell cookbook refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thank you for the link.  Is there any way to comment on your article?  I had to make a number of small changes to get it to work for me and I'd like to share the changes with others so they don't stumble over the same hurdles.  Also, do you have any advice on how to get it working across thread groups with a csv data reader?