# Jmeter - How to extract JSON response data and assign those to cookie?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I want to extract json response data and assign them to next request cookies. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206418/how-to-modify-add-to-cookie-in-jmeter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify / add to Cookie in JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206418/how-to-modify-add-to-cookie-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can extract the required value from JSON using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor). See [Jayway JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) to learn more about JSONPath.
2. Once you have a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding the value you can use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to configure JMeter to send an extra cookie.